# Music don't stops playing when the target isn't visible anymore (Object Reco)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm having some troubles with my AR App (I use Unity and Vuforia). It should play music and add a 3d Character on top of the target if the Target Object is visible, and stop doing so if it isn't visible anymore. Everything works fine, except the music doesn't stop playing always (sometimes it does). I attached the script to the Object Target.

I tried out onBecameInvisible, I tried out using a boolean (visiability), I tried out setting the GameObject active/inactive and I tried the onTrackingFound Method but all of them don't work properly and the music not always stops playing.

Does someone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance :)

```
protected override void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        base.OnTrackingFound();
        m_GameObjectAnimator.SetBool("juggle", true);
        //visiability = true;
        //gameObject.SetActive(true);
        MusicCandyGrabber.Play();
    }

    protected override void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        base.OnTrackingLost();
        m_GameObjectAnimator.SetBool("juggle", false);
        //visiability = false;
        //gameObject.SetActive(false);
        MusicCandyGrabber.Stop();
    }
    void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        MusicCandyGrabber.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Is OnTrackingLos not running? Have you debugged your code to verify that you are actually hitting that method? Otherwise you might just not have a proper AudioSource reference.

Comment: no its just running somtimes but not always and yes it's hitting the method

Comment: You must be using extended tracking feature,  so the target is never lost. I would disable extending tracking and maybe use coroutines to dumping tracking lost events. Otherwise you should explore Vuforia API to maybe use some additional listeners of tracking state changes to your advantage.

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].